# Optimizing the linear correlation with monotone, continuous transformations.

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, optimization

$\newcommand{\Cor}{\operatorname{Cor}}\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}} \newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$So i have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are not lineary related.

Thus $\left|\Cor(X,Y)\right|\neq1$ with $\Cor(X,Y)=\frac{\Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\Var(X)}\cdot\sqrt{\Var(Y)}}$. However i suspect, that they are linealry related after transforming both axes.

Is it possible to find a continous and monotonous function $f$, so that $\left|\Cor(f(X),f(Y))\right|$ is maximized for all $f$?
If not,  are there any non-trivial constraints on $X$ and $Y$ to make it possible?
If i can't maximize, is there an Algorithm, which lets me at least find functions with Correlations converging to the supremum?
Can i put additional constraints on $f$ to make an existing solution unique?

Has anyone encountered similar problems and is able to point at some literature,that might be helpful in order to solve this?